# Android Customized Camera getting the same resolution of the native camera

Tags: android, camera

I am developing an app using Customized Camera. we succeed on making a custom camera and taking pictures, but the thing is, the resolution is not good as n native camera.
my question is. how to improve the quality of the picture taken by a customized camera?

how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to see your CameraActivity.java ? By using this intent:

```
android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
```

we can launch the camera and can capture the photo/snap. Using the above mentioned intent, we are just launching the in-built camera application.

Answer (score 0):

According to Android documentation setPictureSize() is used to define the capture size.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize(int, int)

Follow this link you can have more idea.